# Magento 1.9 Get website code by SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, multi-website

I have a Magento 1.9 site that I have created 4 websites (UK, USA, etc..) in admin.

I have products added to only a certain website.

How can I get website code by product SKU programmatically? So I can see which website that a product is associated to?

Is it possible with product model?

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(10); //10 is product id
$websiteIds = $_product->getWebsiteIds();
foreach($websiteIds as $websiteId){
    echo Mage::getModel('core/website')->load($websiteId)->getData("code").'<br/>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I must get the website code from a certain SKU, if it's possible?

Comment: Okay. Please check. I updated answer.

Comment: Great, I'll test and get back.

Comment: Sorry I missed something when I did test of your code. Your code get me the Store Code not the website Code. I need website code.

Comment: I have edited your answer so it gets Website Code instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only sku,You can try this code.

`$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku', $your_sku);`

instead of

`$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(10); //10 is product id`